# Java parse string using regex into variables

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract variables from a string.

```
String format = "x:y";
String string = "Marty:McFly";
```

Then

```
String x = "Marty";
String y = "McFly";
```

but the format can be anything it could look like this y?x => McFly?Marty

How to solve this using regex?

Edit: current solution

```
        String delimiter = format.replace(Y, "");
        delimiter = delimiter.replaceAll(X, "");
        delimiter = "\\"+delimiter;

        String strings[] = string.split(delimiter);

        String x; 
        String y;
        if(format.startsWith(X)){
             x = strings[0];
             y = strings[1];
        }else{
             y = strings[0];
             x = strings[1];
        }

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
```

This works well, but I would prefer more clean solution.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Are you sure you dont want a `Map`?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with regex, once you learn enough regex to write the pattern.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: You will need to write some Java code.

Comment: Well I have a solution with finding a delimiter, then splitting the string and looking which value is first and assigning but there has to be a better way.

Comment: @Edalol Show what you have, and explain why that is not good enough.

Comment: Edited and added current solution

Comment: @Reimeus not really sure what you mean, I have the pattern and then the String, its not like that in the string I have x=Marty:y=McFly so I could parse it easy into the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex `(\\w)(\\W)(\\w)`

This will find any alphanumeric characters followed by any non alpha-numeric followed by another set of alpha numeric characters. The parenthesis will group the finds so group 1 will be parameter 1, group 2 will be the delimiter and group 3 will be parameter 2.

Comparing parameter 1 with parameter 2 can determine which lexical order they go in.

**Sample**

```
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    testString("x:y", "Marty:McFly");
    testString("x?y", "Marty?McFly");
    testString("y:x", "Marty:McFly");
    testString("y?x", "Marty?McFly");
  }

  /**
   * 
   */
  private static void testString(String format, String string) {
    String regex = "(\\w)(\\W)(\\w)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(format);

    if (!matcher.find()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("no match found");

    String delimiter = matcher.group(2);

    String param1 = matcher.group(1); 
    String param2 = matcher.group(3); 


    String[] split = string.split("\\" + delimiter);
    String x;
    String y;
    switch(param1.compareTo(param2)) {
      case 1:
        x = split[1];
        y = split[0];
        break;
      case -1:
      case 0:
      default:
        x = split[0];
        y = split[1];
    };

    System.out.println("String x: " + x);
    System.out.println("String y: " + y);

    System.out.println(String.format("%s%s%s", x, delimiter, y));
    System.out.println();
  }
```

This approach will allow you to have any type of format not just x and y. You can have any format that matches the regular expression.

Comment: yes this was exactly my goal as the format could be name:surname for example!

Comment: If that is the case the regex would have to be changed to `(\\w+)(\\W)(\\w+)` as the current regex only looks for  1 alphanumeric on both side of a non alphanumeric

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for regex at all.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("x:y", "Marty:McFly");
    test("y?x", "McFly?Marty");
}
public static void test(String format, String input) {
    if (format.length() != 3 || Character.isLetterOrDigit(format.charAt(1))
                             || (format.charAt(0) != 'x' || format.charAt(2) != 'y') &&
                                (format.charAt(0) != 'y' || format.charAt(2) != 'x'))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid format: \"" + format + "\"");
    int idx = input.indexOf(format.charAt(1));
    if (idx == -1 || input.indexOf(format.charAt(1), idx + 1) != -1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input: \"" + input + "\"");
    String x, y;
    if (format.charAt(0) == 'x') {
        x = input.substring(0, idx);
        y = input.substring(idx + 1);
    } else {
        y = input.substring(0, idx);
        x = input.substring(idx + 1);
    }
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
}
```

*Output*

```
x = Marty
y = McFly
x = Marty
y = McFly
```

---

If the format string can be changed to be a regex, then using [named-capturing groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) will make it very simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("(?<x>.*?):(?<y>.*)", "Marty:McFly");
    test("(?<y>.*?)\\?(?<x>.*)", "McFly?Marty");
}
public static void test(String regex, String input) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    if (! m.matches())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input: \"" + input + "\"");
    String x = m.group("x");
    String y = m.group("y");
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
}
```

Same output as above, including value order.

Comment: Overtly complicated solution to a simple problem. the Op can either just hard code a delimiter or use regex to simplify

Comment: @locus2k OP is asking how to extract values for `x` and `y` when a `format` string and an `input` string is supplied, where the `format` string specifies the delimiter and the order of `x` and `y`. This is the answer. Since that is what OP receives, there is no "hard code a delimiter", or "use regex to simplify".

Comment: This is nearly the same as my solution, logic-wise and it works, but I am asking whether there is any other way to simplify it, or use different approach possibly a regex? I really dont know, thats why I ask for an advice.

Comment: @Edalol Not if your parse specification is the `format` string you're showing, where the parsing logic has to determine the separator character and the `x` vs `y` order from that format string. Now, if the parsing logic could receive a regex as the parsing specification, that's a different story.